# How to subclass a vectorizer in scikit-learn without repeating all parameters in the constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, subclass, countvectorizer

I am trying to create a custom vectorizer by subclassing the `CountVectorizer`. The vectorizer will stem all the words in the sentence before counting the word frequency. I then use this vectorizer in a pipeline which works fine when I do `pipeline.fit(X,y)`.

However, when I try to set a parameter with `pipeline.set_params(rf__verbose=1).fit(X,y)`, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their __init__ (no varargs). <class 'features.extraction.labels.StemmedCountVectorizer'> with constructor (self, *args, **kwargs) doesn't  follow this convention.
```

Here is my custom vectorizer:

```
class StemmedCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords=True)
        super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def build_analyzer(self):
        analyzer = super(StemmedCountVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
        return lambda doc: ([' '.join([self.stemmer.stem(w) for w in word_tokenize(word)]) for word in analyzer(doc)])
```

I understand that I could set every single parameter of the `CountVectorizer` class but it doesn't seem to follow the DRY principle.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're subclassing CountVectorizer, why would you need to initialize both the parent and the subclass?

Comment: If I don't initialize the `CountVectorizer`, all the fields it needs to count word occurrences won't be initialized (the vocabulary for example). As I am using the scikit-learn `Pipeline`, I only pass the `StemmedCountVectorizer` to the pipeline so I cannot use `partial` trick

Comment: I don't think I have enough information to appropriately answer this question then.  If you subclass `CountVectorizer`, wouldn't you only need to initalize the subclass, and then have full access to everything you would otherwise need in `CountVectorizer` in your subclass `StemmedCountVectorizer`?

Comment: I didn't look closely at your subclass... why are you explicitly calling super for each method call?  You should already have access to the parent  class methods.  There is no need to explicitly redefine them - you only do that if you're changing (overriding) the method in the subclass.

Comment: My bad, the `get_params` was an experiment to fix this issue which didn't work, I'll edit the question. For the `build_analyzer`, I have to use the super class as I am using it in the same function I want to extend. The reason I'm doing this is that the sklearn pipeline requires the `build_analyzer` method and I do not need to override the whole method for my subclass (I actually found this snippet in a NLP tutorial).

Answer (score 7):

I have no experience with vectorizers in `sklearn`, however I ran into a similar problem. I've implemented a custom estimator, let's call it `MyBaseEstimator` for now, extending `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator`. Then I've implemted a few other custom sub-estimators extending `MyBaseEstimator`. The `MyBaseEstimator` class defined multiple arguments in its `__init__`, and I didn't want to have the same arguments in the `__init__` methods of each of the sub-estimators.

However, without re-defining the arguments in the subclasses, much of `sklearn` functionality didn't work, specificlaly, setting these parameters for cross-validation. It seems that `sklearn` expects that all the relevant parameters for an estimator can be retrieved and modified using the `BaseEstimator.get_params()` and `BaseEstimator.set_params()` methods. And these methods, when invoked on one of the subclasses, do not return any parameters defined in the baseclass.

To work around this I implemented an overriding `get_params()` in `MyBaseEstimator` that uses an ugly hack to merge the parameters of the dynamic type (one of it's sub-calsses) with the parameters defined by its own `__init__`.

Here's the same ugly hack applied to your `CountVectorizer`...

```py
import copy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


class SubCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def __init__(self, p1=1, p2=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        params = super().get_params(deep)
        # Hack to make get_params return base class params...
        cp = copy.copy(self)
        cp.__class__ = CountVectorizer
        params.update(CountVectorizer.get_params(cp, deep))
        return params


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scv = SubCountVectorizer(p1='foo', input='bar', encoding='baz')
    scv.set_params(**{'p2': 'foo2', 'analyzer': 'bar2'})
    print(scv.get_params())
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```py
{'p1': None, 'p2': 'foo2',
'analyzer': 'bar2', 'binary': False,
'decode_error': 'strict', 'dtype': <class 'numpy.int64'>,
'encoding': 'baz', 'input': 'bar',
'lowercase': True, 'max_df': 1.0, 'max_features': None,
'min_df': 1, 'ngram_range': (1, 1), 'preprocessor': None,
'stop_words': None, 'strip_accents': None,
'token_pattern': '(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
'tokenizer': None, 'vocabulary': None}
```

which shows that `sklearn`'s `get_params()` and `set_params()` now both work and also passing keyword-arguments of both the subbclass and the baseclass to the subclass `__init__` works.

Not sure how robust this is and whether it solves your exact issue, but it may be of use to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are subclassing to add some additional methods (or override existing ones) I would expect you would only be instantiating the subclass, and therefore would have to provide the initalization arguments.

If you are creating several instances which all share mostly the same initialization data, with one or two instance specific changes, then one solution could be to "freeze" the common data using `partial`.  For example (generic contrived example follows):

```
from functools import partial

class Person():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Bob(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,age,weight):
        super().__init__(name,age)
        self.weight = weight

    def refer_to_thyself(self):
        print('My name is {} and I am {} years old and weigh {} lbs.'.format(
            self.name,self.age,self.weight))

Bob_cloner = partial(Bob,'Bob',20)
Bob1 = Bob_cloner(175)
Bob2 = Bob_cloner(185)
Bob1.refer_to_thyself()
Bob2.refer_to_thyself()
```

Here we freeze the name and age using `partial`, and then just let the weight vary amongst the Bobs.