# Meta-programming - How to generate class from template when __class__ is used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, scikit-learn, metaprogramming

I've created class like this to solve issue with signature and feature_names:

```
import copy
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceTreshold


class VarianceThresholdN(VarianceThreshold):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.feature_names = None

    #hack from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430484/how-to-subclass-a-vectorizer-in-scikit-learn-without-repeating-all-parameters-in    
    def get_params(self, deep=True): 
        params = super().get_params(deep)
        cp = copy.copy(self)
        cp.__class__ = VarianceThreshold
        params.update(cp.__class__.get_params(cp, deep))
        return params

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.feature_names = list(X.columns)
        return super().fit(X, y)
```

Unfortunately, I need to create a lot of classes like this, so a lot of copy-paste and replacing two things:
`class VarianceThresholdN(VarianceThreshold):` to `class DifferentClassN(DifferentClass):` and `cp.__class__ = VarianceThreshold` to `cp.__class__ = DifferentClass`.

So there is a clear template, but due to `cp.__class__ = ...` I can't use mix-ins.

Probably this code could be generated with jinja templates, but is there any way to avoid it, with some pythonic trick from meta-programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand what that's supposed to do, you're pretty much just calling super() twice as far as I can tell, with the second version doing that explicitly.

> Probably this code could be generated with jinja templates, but is there any way to avoid it, with some pythonic trick from meta-programming?

If your pattern is that you always want to "swap" `self.__class__` for its parent, you can just access it using `__bases__`, or `mro()[1]`:

- `cls.__bases__` is a tuple of all the superclasses of `cls`, it's exactly what you put in the parens (excluding kwargs)
- `cls.mro()` is the "method resolution order", it would work fine for this specific (completely linear) case: it's a sequence of all classes to go through when handling an attribute or method call, starting from `cls` (included) and ending at `object` (which is the original ancestor of all Python classes).

Comment: If you mean replacing `cp.__class__ = VarianceThreshold` with `cp.__class__ = cp.__class__.__bases__[-1]` it seems to work for my case. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. If you're using `__bases__` then `__bases__[0]` should also work: your `__bases__` is a tuple with a single element.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. In my original case also I have some mix-ins on 'left side' of base class and in this case, I need to get last element of tuple so [-1].